# C# - Facebook - Publish on page wall as Admin

Tags: c#, facebook

this is my little snipped of code, i'm trying to post on Facebook Fan Page with C# as admin.
Everythings works but when I look at the post on the page, was released from my profile and not from the page. my profile is the admin of the page.
I create the access token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with "manage_pages, offline_access, publish_stream" properties.

Thank you for the help

```
public bool PostImage(string pageAccessToken, string Status, string Imagepath)
{
    try
    {
        var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(Imagepath)
        }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(Imagepath));

        var fb = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);

        fb.Post("/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/photos", new 
        Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "message", Status },
        { "source", mediaObject } }

        );

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i am having exactly same problem